# Get string without formatting markers in JavaScript with the help of a RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help. I've this string here in my JavaScript function:

```
let test = '{#ff0000ES}ISTKZWEI'
```

Now I need to remove every color formatting from this string so that it looks like this:

```
console.log(test); // <-- ESISTKZWEI
```

I'm not really good in RegEx but tried the following:

```
{#[a-z0-9]{6}.*
```

This matches everything at the end which is not what I want, but it's already matching the initial `{` and the hex color string.

How can I cut now around the `ES`? Inside my color marking there can be a longer word than `ES` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group for the part after the match to keep ES and match the `}`

```
{#[a-f0-9]{6}(\w*)}
```

- `{` Match opening curly
- `#[a-f0-9]{6}` Match # and 6 repetitions of a-f or 0-9
- `(\w*)` Capture **group 1**, match optional word chars (In case there are none and you still want to remove the `}`
- `}` Match closing curly

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I49hQ7/1)

In the replacement use group 1.

```js
let test = '{#ff0000ES}ISTKZWEI';
console.log(test.replace(/{#[a-f0-9]{6}(\w*)}/, "$1"));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Thats wat I was looking for and what my RegEx missed.

Comment: I've tried it now with multiple formatters: `{#ff0000ES}K{#ff0000IST}A{#ff0000FÜNF}` This only removes the first formatter but I need multiple.

Comment: @Mr.Jo You could use `{#[a-f0-9]{6}([^{}]*)}` see https://regex101.com/r/POIqFh/1 as the pattern and add the `/g` for global flag `console.log(test.replace(/{#[a-f0-9]{6}(\w*)}/g, "$1"));`

Comment: Now it's perfect! What a great help!